# Field value change system time

Tags: php

Hello wondering how should i be able to change a value of a certain field if the a date of the system time was met. I was thinking on the line of this. Any ideas/help is appreciated.

```
   if('y','4','d'){ field='changevalue' }
```

EDIT: field is status: with values ENROLL and UNENROLLED, My idea is once the system time is april The value of status should turn to unenrolled.

Comment: What kind of field? A form field? A class field? What does your conditional represent? You need way more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My idea is once the system time is april The value of status should turn to unenrolled."

```
$month = date("n");
if ($month == 4) {
  // It is April
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="<? if(/* your condition */){ echo "changevalue";} ?>" >
```

Didnt test it but I think this should work.